# Adding an image in ActionListener

Tags: java, image, graphics, actionlistener, paint

I am trying to make a JButton that displays an image in the JPanel when pressed - allowing the user to choose the location in the panel. I am using the following methods to paint:

```
public void paint(Graphics g, URL path) {
    Image img = getImage(path);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.drawImage(img, getX(),getY(),50,50, null);
}

public Image getImage(URL path) {
    Image temp = null;
    try
    {
        temp = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return temp;
}
```

When I call paint(), I get a null pointer exception in my last line of my ActionListener:

```
dogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            Graphics g = null;
            Animal animal = new Animal();
            animal.paint(g, main.class.getResource("/Animals/dog.jpg"));
        }
```

I'm a little confused overall about how to use ActionListeners.  This is my first project so I apologize for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: what ?  `Graphics g = null;`??

Answer (score 1):

You have set
`Graphics g = null;`

Initialize g with something other than null.

I would recommend overriding `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` of the JPanel where you plan to paint and use this graphics.